# Как зайти в phpmyadmin на ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, ubuntu

Установил LAMP на Ubuntu, и не могу открыть phpmyadmin. Так выдает 404

```
http://localhost/tools/phpmyadmin

http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Через консольку `mysql -uroot-proot` все норм

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 63
Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

потом ввожу `CREATE DATABASE box;`. Пишет

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'box'
```

Comment: Создайте нового пользователя БД и дайте ему права GRANT ALL

Answer (score 2):

вот это мне помогло с *ubuntu 14.04* (взято [отсюда](http://start.besthost.by/post/86)):

### Установка/удаление Apache2 + php5 + MySQL + phpMyAdmin

#### Установка

Обновим информацию о пакетах:

```
apt-get update
```

Обновим систему:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Установим *apache*:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Запустим *апач*:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 start
```

Также можно остановить или перезапустить *апач*:

для *ubuntu*:

sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart

для *debian*:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Установим *php* и зависимости:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Установим *MySQL-сервер*:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Необходимо изменить пароль *root* к серверу *БД*:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password новый_пароль
```

Установим *phpMyAdmin*:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Делаем "мягкую ссылку" (*symlink*) на директорию, гда находится *phpMyAdmin*:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/pma
```

#### Удаление

Удаляем пакеты в обратном порядке:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin php5-mysql php5 mysql-server apache2
```

Удаляем зависимости:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2.2-common apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5
```

Удаляем директории (только *apache2*):

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/ /etc/php5/apache2/
```

---

дело в том, что у вас нет директории *phpmyadmin*, а есть директория *pma*,  и надо делать *мягкую ссылку* (*symlink*).

потом, как пропишете *symlink*, перезагрузите сервер, вызовите его так:

```
http://localhost/pma
```

или переименуйте папку в *phpmyadmin*, она будет в `var/www`.

Answer (score -3):

Можно сделать символическую ссылку с каталога *phpmyadmin*, например, в корень сайта, и затем уже входить по этому адресу.