# Не могу установить PHP на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, терминал

пытаюсь установить php но мне выдает ошибку при самом update и потом когда устанавливаю php.Все делаю через терминал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/121961/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-phpmyadmin-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu">ru.SO Вот смотрите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

при апдейте тебе выдает ошибку потому, что ты добавил левый репозиторий. не важно. а вот зачем ты пытаешься установить libapache-mod-php5 - совсем не ясно.
сделай просто

sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2

sudo apt-get install php

убунта достаточно умная, чтобы сама дефолтному серверу добавить правильный php-модуль

p.s. и поставь английский дефолтным языком в системе, так ты найдешь сразу целую кучу решений простым копипастом

p.p.s libapache-mod-php5  не находится, потому, что ты действуешь по копипасту старой инструкции. php5  уже не поставляется в новых убунтах,  в них, по дефолту, идет php7

поэтому

`apt-cache search apache | grep php
libapache2-mod-php - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module) (default)
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)`

apt падает при первой же ошибке, а поскольку второй пакет не найден (ошибка), то и первый он не ставит.

т.е. если первый вариант не сработает, попробуй 
`apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`, который и поставит дефолтный модуль php7

Comment: apache или apache2. потому что я раньше устанавливал именно apache2

Comment: исправил, apache2 конечно